# What is the difference between "learnable parameters" and "weights" in neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks

I think the learnable parameters are the set of all weights and biases in the neural network, but is it true in general?

Comment: The terms 'parameters' and 'weights' are used interchangeably and are learned during the training. Usually, the term 'parameters' is used predominantly in Statistics and 'weights'  in the Machine Learning community; they are applicable to all types of models and not necessarily to only Neural Networks.

Comment: @Nizam So, is it safe to refer to learnable parameters in deep learning as weights?

Comment: Yes, works fine.

Comment: Although, be aware that there may be more learnable parameters of the network than just weights.

Comment: @ajax2112 Do you mean biases? Though, I think it's not good to refer to weights and biases together as weights.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Learnable parameters is a broader term an weights is a subset of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learnable parameters usually means weights and biases,  but there is more to it - the term encompasses anything that can be adjusted (i.e. *learned*) during training.

There are weights and biases in the bulk matrix computations; when thinking e.g. about a `Conv2d` operation with its number of filters and kernel size.

There are also *parameters* that are learned in layers such as `BatchNorm`, which are referred to as parameters (not just *weights*) perhaps because they are often discussed in terms of simple equations, where they look like coefficients in an equation. The parameters of this equation (the *scale* and *shift*) are learnt during training, so are included in the number of learnable parameters, but are a bit different from normal weights and biases. Have a look at the [**original paper (Ioffe, Szegedy, 2015)**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) for more information/interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was wrong. Right now my reputation is not enough to comment on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/457840/229142) answer, so I'll write the addendum here.

The user n1k31t4 is right that there's more to *learnable parameters* than *weights* and *biases*.  He proves his words with [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) paper. I read it and found the exact phrase that proves his words.

Page three, upper-right corner, below the formula. The paragraph was about the parameters of `BatchNorm`.

> These  parameters  are  learned  along  with  the  original model parameters